# Django Dopzone form is not validating

Tags: django, dropzone.js

I'm trying to build multiple image uploader that is connected to posts/listings on my website. I was able to set everything but when I click upload, form is not validating and photos are not being saved.
Here is what I have up to now.

models.py

```
class UploadFileModel(models.Model):
    # listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, blank=False, default=1)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UploadFileModel
    fields = ["file",]
```

views.py

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)

@require_POST
def upload(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print request.FILES
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse(status=201)
        else:
            # print form.errors
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
    return HttpResponse(status=404)

def photo_upload(request, id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=id)
    context = {"listing": listing,}

    return render(request, "dropzone_photo.html", context)
```

And in the end here is part of the template:

```
<form class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
   <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="listing" value="{{ listing.id }}" id="listing_id"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

I'm using Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone with following configuration:

```
url: "/dropzone/upload/" + $("#listing_id").val(),
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a Django form here. Use this i your view:

```
@require_POST
def upload(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        for filename, uploaded_file in request.FILES.iteritems():
            image = UploadFileModel()
            image.file = uploaded_file
            image.save()
            return HttpResponse(status=201)
    return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

This won't work:

```
file = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You need to supply the name of the directory your uploading to and the MEDIA_ROOT will be prepended to that name by Django. Example:

```
file = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
```

The path will then "/media/uploads/..." if your MEDIA_ROOT is "media".

Comment: thank you for your reply, you have set me on the right path. With your help I was able to make what I was looking for. Only thing about your code is that `return HttpResponse(status=201)` should be out of for loop in order to upload more than one image.

Comment: I think I was using ajax and returning 201 for every file uploaded... Anyway, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end this is what I was looking for:
model.py

```
class UploadFileModel(models.Model):
listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, blank=False)
file = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
```

view.py

```
@require_POST
def upload(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        for filename, uploaded_file in request.FILES.iteritems():
            print uploaded_file
            image = UploadFileModel()
            image.file = uploaded_file
            listing_instance = Listing.objects.get(id=id)
            image.listing = listing_instance
            image.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=201)
    return HttpResponse(status=404)

def photo_upload(request, id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=id)
    context = {"listing": listing,}
    return render(request, "dropzone_photo.html", context)
```

and template is as it is in my question.